# AWS Autogenerated SDK on Android - Clock Skew Fix

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, api-gateway

How can I fix clock skew for an android app using an AWS Autogenerated SDK using [CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-android/docs/reference/com/amazonaws/auth/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.html) along with APIClientFactory?

Most AWS SDK calls seem to have it fixed automatically--but those done by the autogenerated SDK do not.

I'm looking for something similar to `setTimeOffset`--see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/managing-device-time-with-the-aws-mobile-sdks/.

Update:  Or https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html#correctClockSkew-property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.  If you parse the error message, you can determine the offset for your device, then set it using:

```
SDKGlobalConfiguration.setGlobalTimeOffset(offset); //in seconds
```

Once that's set the auto-generated SDKs will take into account the offset when it signs the request.

A couple of things to keep in mind:

- make sure you get the positive/negative offset correct, I had to multiple * -1 to correct mine.
- I found I needed to synchronize my api calls (ensure only 1 was called at a time) because the math required to determine the offset required using any previous offset to account for clocks changing several times throughout the lifetime of the app.

*Documentation: https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-android/docs/reference/index.html*